# Microchip PIC - Flexible Interchip Communication Bus

Tags: i2c, microchip, bus, pic32, pic24

I'm working on the design of flexible Module-Module Bus.

Basically, each module will have a micro controller likely to be on the PIC24 / PIC32 family.

The bus will be running through a RJ11 connector and has to be inexpensive.

It needs the following features:
 - No master / slave configuration but arbitration (like CAN)
 - Auto-addressing 
 - 2 or 1 wire that can be flipped
 - correct data rate.

The idea at first was to use an I2C bus with a third line for addressing. Though for cabling reason, the bus should support to reassign the lines if it's crossed and the I2C microchip module has hard position on pins.

SPI is obviously not the solution.
CAN module could work but the limit of 8 byte and the need of transceiver is quite annoying.
LIN requires master.

Now I'm looking of a way to use the UART module with loopback mode somehow as the PPS could reassign the pins.

The other solution would be to create a bus from scratch and code everything, but it would be time consuming.

Any experience and solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this won't exactly be an answer, but I am using a SPI bus with select lines that run up a back-plane connector shifting a spot on each board (so 0 always selects its self, 1 selects board below and 5 board above) This back-plane talks to up-to 6 PIC32s all connected to a single SPI. Now what you could do is use a word to gate the actions instead of select lines (using 3 lines) and when the right gate word is detected the PIC knows the next few words are for it. Just a thought...